# Getting a variable from the ng-change function angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I eventually need to create a select box with 4 options - Module 1 to 4. When an option is selected I need to send the number which was selected to the controller so that it can return different datasets for a chart.

That is the end goal, however experimenting with different code pens I simplified my problem down to just trying to get a variable from an input box.

I can get the value to appear on the template but I can not access it in the controller. How can I make the function in the controller work with the passed input data?

html

```
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-cloak>
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
  <p>Start editing and see your changes reflected here!</p>
</div>

<input placeholder="Module" type="text" ng-change="moduleChange(myModule)"
       ng-model="myModule" ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}">

{{myModule}}
</body>
```

script.js

```
angular.module('plunker', []).controller('MainCtrl',
  function($scope) {
     $scope.name = 'Plunker';
     $scope.moduleChange = function(myModule) {
          alert(myModule);
          console.log(myModule);
          $scope.name = myModule;
     }
});
```

I thought that I would get an alert every time I changed the input but nothing is happening. nothing is logged to the console and the $scope.name variable appears to not change.

Where am I going wrong? Thx

Also any pointers for making it work inside a select box would be great too!

[plunkr](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/NV3jk6gPmBHF7XvF?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1)

Comment: Have you tried removing the ng-model-options?

Comment: Thanks. I just tried but still no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `ng-controller="MainCtrl"` to the outer element (thats the reason why the function was not fired):

```
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-cloak>
```

You don't need to pass the value into the function, you have the value with `ng-model`:

```
<input placeholder="Module" type="text" ng-change="moduleChange()" ng-model="myModule" ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}">

$scope.moduleChange = function() {
          alert($scope.myModule);
          console.log($scope.myModule);
          $scope.name = $scope.myModule;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Simple as that.